# Magento 404 on Sub Pages

Tags: magento, ubuntu, configuration, apache2, http-status-code-404

I just restored our Magento website on a different server running apache2 on ubuntu. The home page pulls up just fine but if I try to go to any other page, I get a 404.

**Permissions**

- All files are 660
- All directories are 770 All files and directories
- All files and directories belong to the www-data group

**Things I've Tried**

- check all the website and store ids
- add /index.php/ between the domain and page path
- clear temporary files

Nothing appears in the log files other than the standard 404 lines in the access.log and error.log.

**apache2 .conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin serveradmin@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/default/"
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/default/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        php_admin_flag engine on
        php_admin_value open_basedir none
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 10G
    php_value max_execution_time 1800000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset Off

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

**Log File Output**

```
==> /var/log/apache2/oem1-error.log <==
[Tue Oct 15 12:32:21 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.4] File does not exist: /var/www/gearhead_oem1/admin

==> /var/log/apache2/oem1-access.log <==
192.168.0.4 - - [15/Oct/2013:12:32:21 -0600] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Check your .htaccess file. May be you modified that file when you deployed in old server..If possible can you please post your .htaccess code here..?and your log file also ..

Comment: Try restoring your .htaccess to the one included with Magento.  See if that works first.

Comment: @Axel Great idea. Also a no go.

Comment: Have you tried disabling `Use Web Server Rewrites` under `System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimizations` and seeing if the URLs work?  Also are you sure that mod_rewrite is enabled for Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with rewrites. In Ubuntu:

Run:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and then:

```
service apache2 restart
```

`mod_rewrite` will now be enabled!

Comment: I also added php5-curl to your answer. a2enmod rewrite got me most of the way there but I was still getting some curl errors.